# Converting and Displaying a LaTeX Document within a WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, latex, pdflatex

I have a couple questions related to using LaTeX within a C#/WPF application.

The application I'm developing writes reports using LaTeX. I'll then need to convert those LaTeX documents into something I can display to the screen.  This is where my first question comes in: I know I have two choices for converting the LaTeX document -- conversion to .dvi or conversion to .pdf -- what I wonder is which format would be the best speed-wise *and* for displaying? I'm unsure how to display a .pdf or a .dvi file within a WPF application -- is there some way to put them into a Canvas control or any other WPF control?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily display pdf's using the acrobat control (or if you're feeling lazy, with the Internet Explorer control). Just put one in a Winform Hosting Control and call its loading method.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using the Acrobat control just due to any licensing things that might require.

Comment: The reader is free to use as you wish. You'll be in a world of hurt if you're going to try rendering pdf's manually..